# CS0119 'DataGridView' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this error when try to use my method with DataGridview :/

```
public class Laboratory3
{
    public static void Table (double x, double y, DataGridView DGV)
    {
        DGV.Rows.Add(x.ToString("F1"), y.ToString("F5"));
    } 
    
    public static double Count3(double x)
    {
        double rez = 0.5 * Math.Exp(Math.Sin(x)) - x - 1;
        return rez;
    }

    public static void Cycle() 
    {
        double x = 0;
        double n = (10 - 0) / 0.5 + 1;
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            double Result = Laboratory3.Count3(x);
            Laboratory3.Table(x, Result, DataGridView);
            x += 0.5;
        }
   }
```

What should I change for successfully add lines?

Comment: The `Cycle()` method is passing the `DataGridView` type instead of an instance.  Pass an instance of that type instead.

Comment: `public static void Cycle(DataGridView dgv) { .. Table(x, Result, dgv); .. }`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you are using the type name where you should be using a variable. I can't tell from the code you show here what you are calling the DataGridView, b ut the line that says:

```
Laboratory3.Table(x, Result, DataGridView);
```

should probably be:

```
Laboratory3.Table(x, Result, myDataGrid);
```

This assumes that the DataGridView on the form is call, myDataGrid, of course. I can't tell from this code how you are getting access to a DataGridView. The control would normally be defined on a XAML form, and I'm pretty sure that controls are private to the form on which they are defined, so not be available from another class.